# Tunnel socket could not established

Tags: node.js, sockets, npm, proxy, request

I am using this package to get the videos from Tiktok [tiktok-package](https://github.com/drawrowfly/tiktok-scraper).

It's working fine. But now after some time, I could not get any data maybe my IP blocked. So I used proxy for this which gives me **error**

**Error**

Exception thrown in tiktok scraper Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http

I run below lines in my project, but still, it's not working

```
npm config set proxy http://myproxy:port
npm config set https-proxy http://myproxy:port
```

Code

```
'use strict';
 const TikTokScraper = require('tiktok-scraper');

 var main = async(user, numOfVideos) => {

 try {
    var data = [];

    var myPorxy = 'http://proxy_host:port' //my proxy and port
    const posts = await TikTokScraper.user(user, { number: numOfVideos, proxy: myPorxy }
        );

    if (posts) {
        posts.collector.map(post => {
            data.push(post);
        });
    }

    //return data;
    console.log(data);
   } catch (error) {
        return error;
  }
  };
  main('zachking', 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at the [Options](https://github.com/drawrowfly/tiktok-scraper#options) for the packet your are using, it seems like you don't have to specify the protocol if you are using a http proxy:

```
// Set proxy {string[] | string default: ''}
// http proxy: 127.0.0.1:8080
// socks proxy: socks5://127.0.0.1:8080
// You can pass proxies as an array and scraper will randomly select a proxy from the array to execute the requests
proxy: '',
```

Assuming everything else is correct `var myPorxy = 'proxy_host:port'` should work.

Comment: when I used the proxy without http I got error "Socket connection not found"

Comment: Are you sure that the proxy you are using is a working http proxy? I just tested you code and everything works as expected. Changing the npm proxy settings is btw not needed for this to work.

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting if you `console.log(error)` the error in the catch block? I noticed that with or without a proxy I am not getting any posts back. This packet is using an unofficial API, maybe you should check with the maintainer if it is still working.